# Does Facebook Respects Do Not Track?

Tags: ios, facebook

When submitting a new app or an app update to the Apple App Review and with Advertising Identifier we have to make a choice in iTunes Connect. The last checkbox declares:

> I, Jay Doe, confirm that this app, and any third party that interfaces with this app, uses the Advertising Identifier checks and honors a user's Limit Ad Tracking setting in iOS and, when it is enabled by a user, this app does not use Advertising Identifier, and any information obtained through the use of the Advertising Identifier, in any way other than for "Limited Advertising Purposes" as defined in the iOS Developer Program License Agreement.

We are using Facebook SDK to track app installations. I didn't find any information about this on Facebook developer portal. All I found is this:

> Does Facebook’s SDK for iOS access the IDFA?
>
> The Facebook SDK includes code to access Apple’s Advertising Identifier (IDFA), but that code is only executed in certain situations.
>
> The Facebook SDK for iOS only accesses IDFAs in the following scenarios:
>   1) if your app serves ads within the app through Facebook’s Audience Network, or 2) if your app logs app installs or other mobile App Events in order to attribute those events to your ad campaigns.
>
> If you are not logging App Events with the FBSDKAppEvents class, then the Facebook SDK is not accessing the IDFAs. Additionally, the Facebook SDK does not require AdSupport.framework to be included.
>
> If you want to track App Events without collecting IDFA, you can disable IDFA collection within your app dashboard in the advanced setting section.

I am suspecting that Facebook does not respect this rule because I didn't find `advertisingTrackingEnabled` bool in their SDK. What I found is following:

```
+ (NSString *)advertiserID
{
  NSString *result = nil;

  Class ASIdentifierManagerClass = fbsdkdfl_ASIdentifierManagerClass();
  if ([ASIdentifierManagerClass class]) {
    ASIdentifierManager *manager = [ASIdentifierManagerClass sharedManager];
    result = [[manager advertisingIdentifier] UUIDString];
  }

  return result;
}
```

I am using following pod:

```
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found this.

```
+ (FBSDKAdvertisingTrackingStatus)advertisingTrackingStatus
{
  static dispatch_once_t fetchAdvertisingTrackingStatusOnce;
  static FBSDKAdvertisingTrackingStatus status;

  dispatch_once(&fetchAdvertisingTrackingStatusOnce, ^{
    status = FBSDKAdvertisingTrackingUnspecified;
    Class ASIdentifierManagerClass = fbsdkdfl_ASIdentifierManagerClass();
    if ([ASIdentifierManagerClass class]) {
      ASIdentifierManager *manager = [ASIdentifierManagerClass sharedManager];
      if (manager) {
        status = [manager isAdvertisingTrackingEnabled] ? FBSDKAdvertisingTrackingAllowed : FBSDKAdvertisingTrackingDisallowed;
      }
    }
  });

  return status;
}
```

Which makes me very happy, looks like Facebook does everything correctly.

The reason I couldn't find the boolean is the `is` prefix in the `isAdvertisingTrackingEnabled`.